# Change image properties on hover when hovering element which trigger when hovering the image

Tags: css, hover

I want to use a code which is able to change image properties when hovering element which trigger when hovering the image. I can only change the triggering element properties on hover. I read that there is a problem that it can't be done if the element which is supposed to change is located before the hovered element - that's my case. In this case I want only to add red outline (I know I can change anything, it's example).

[Here is Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Catchamouse/46g4w9tq/7/)

```
    #overimage
{
position: relative;
line-height: 0;
font-size: 0;
}

.Xevoz_Showdown
{
display: none;
}

.onlinegameimage:hover
{
outline: solid 1px red;       
}

.Xevoz_Showdown_cont:hover .Xevoz_Showdown
{
display: inline;
position: absolute; 
bottom: 82px; 
left: 10px; 
min-height: 25px; 
width: 100px; 
font: 14px/1.0 Times New Roman; 
color: white; 
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

<span id="overimage">

<a href="http://www.superhry.cz/games/300/" target="_blank">

<span class="Xevoz_Showdown_cont">
<img class="onlinegameimage"src="http://www.catchamouse.ic.cz/Xevoz%20showdown.jpg"alt=Xevoz_showdown style="margin: 10px"><span class="Xevoz_Showdown">Xevoz<br />Showdown</span>
</span>
```

Comment: I didn't get it. What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to show a *title* element to an image and you want to highlight the image also if you hover the *title* element. You need to move your "title" element before the image so you can react either to the hover state of the parent element or the *title* element to highlight the image.

```css
#overimage {
    position: relative;
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
}
.Xevoz_Showdown {
    display: none;
}
.Xevoz_Showdown_cont:hover .Xevoz_Showdown {
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    min-height: 25px;
    width: 100px;
    font: 14px/1.0 Times New Roman;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
.Xevoz_Showdown:hover + .onlinegameimage, .onlinegameimage:hover {
    outline: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<span id="overimage">

<a href="http://www.superhry.cz/games/300/" target="_blank">

<span class="Xevoz_Showdown_cont">
    <span class="Xevoz_Showdown">Xevoz<br />Showdown</span>
    <img class="onlinegameimage"src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
</span>
```